# Xamarin Forms custom control or mvvm

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms. I wanted to create a dropdown like component in xamarin forms.

I see two options:

1.- To create a view in xaml and programming all its logic in a view model which then I can use as property of a Page view model and use events to communicate my changes and setters in the other direction, etc.

2.- To create the same view but programming all its logic in the code behind, exposing some events and bindable properties. What I think it would be a custom control.

Which one is a better practice in terms of performance, easy to maintain, etc?

Comment: Have you seen the picker component? 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. Yes I have, but it is not a picker component what I need. Anyways I wanted to know what approach is better because I need to create some "controls" for my current application that are not provided by Xamarin.

Comment: Your controls should not care whether the user is using code-behind or mvvm. You should define properties on your control that drive its behavior, (like Items, Command, etc.) and events that fire out of the control. Then the caller can either handle the events directly in code behind or bind a ViewModel and commands to your control.

If you want the broadest use of your control, you should support both. If you (or your company/team) are the only user of the control, then you can pick one.